# What's the best way to implement AdWords in Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-ads-api

What is the best way to handle Google AdWords in an Android app? I want to implement it like it's done in the *New York Times Magazine* app. A small banner that shows up in the top and show for a while then disappears. Once the banner has been displayed it needs to be registered with my AdWords account.

Any feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a project for this in [Google Labs](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/).